# Parse data from many-to-many relationship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I want to create a function where user be able to report the post if the post content contains something that doesn't follow the guidelines.

What I have so far:

## model/post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'author_id'
  has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy
  scope :reported, -> { distinct.joins(:reports) }

  validates :title, :content, :author_id, presence: true
end
```

## model/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "author_id"
  has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy
end
```

## model/report.rb

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: "author_id"
  belongs_to :post

  validates :content, :user_id, :post_id, :author_id, presence: true
end
```

When the user trying to report the post, user will need to input `content` of the report and the data will be save on the `Report` Model.

This is my `Report` structure:

```
class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :reports do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.references :user
      t.references :author
      t.references :post, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I managed to store the data to the `Report` model/table. 
So, in my `dashboard_controller`, I would like the author of the post noticed that they has some posts that being reported by the user that needs some action/attention from their side (edit or anything)

## controller/dashboard_controller.rb

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  def report
    @reports = current_user.posts.reported
    #render json: @reports
  end
end
```

The result will display the list of posts that user reported.

My questions:

1. How do I display `content` of the report from `reports` table?
2. I added `@reports = current_user.posts.joins(:reports).select("posts.*, reports.*")` in the dashboard_controller, it display the results that I wanted in json, but when I try to iterate like below, it doesn't display anything on views, no errors.

   `<% @reports.each do |report| %>
           <h1><% report.content %></h1>
    <% end %>`
3. As far as I know, calling `.joins` will do SQL queries (N+1) instead of `.includes`. I didn't managed to get it working using `.includes`. Is it fine from what I've done?
4. Or is there any better solutions to what I've done now?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to consider a scoped has_many in this case on the User model as well. `has_many :reported_posts, -> { reported }, class: 'Post'`, saves you a nested call, as you can now do `current_user.reported_posts`

Comment: @bo-oz I'm sorry, I'm not quite understand. Does it will display reported post to the author or user reported post?

Comment: It uses the same relationship as `has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy`, but gives you quicker access to the scope, by including it in the relationship. So basically the resulting query would be the same. It's just that your user shouldn't be concerned about any scopes on a related model. I think it's just a bit nicer calling `current_user.reported_posts` instead of `current_user.posts.reported`. But it's a matter of taste. Just wanted to share it as a tip.

Comment: @bo-oz based on my current structure, I added that to my User model but got `ERROR: column posts.user_id does not exist LINE 1`.

Also, its `class_name: 'Post` right?